# Recreating original ISO from a liveusb

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image, livecd

I have just made a ubuntu live usb. The usb is of 4gb. If I create ISO from usb, it is not having same checksum as original ISO used to make live usb, since this new ISO will be of 4 gb whereas original was lesser. I am using`sudo cat /dev/sdb1 > /home/user/test.iso` to create iso file. I am doing this so that I can check the integrity of live usb anytime. How can I create original ISO from a live usb ?

Comment: Try `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sdb1`?  This reads the device but not only the partition.

Comment: that also gives 4gb iso while original is lesser

Comment: Because your usb is bigger than the iso, the excess part filled with random data remains. When recreating the original iso, that random garbage gets included. Also, you should use `dd` instead of `cat`. First use `ls -l` to check the exact number of bytes in the original iso and `dd` the same number of bytes from the start of `/dev/sdb1`

Comment: If you had an 8GB usb stick your iso would be 8GB too...